# f-string for multiple SQL lines

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, f-string

This one works (one line only):

```
   c.execute(f"SELECT Firm, Platform, `Sale in million` FROM database WHERE Platform IN  ({','.join('?' for _ in list_table)}) ORDER BY Firm", (list_table))
```

But these ones don't (2 lines):

```
c.execute(f"SELECT Firm, Platform, `Sale in million` FROM database 
          WHERE Platform IN  ({','.join('?' for _ in list_table)}) ORDER BY Firm", (list_table))

c.execute(f"SELECT Firm, Platform, `Sale in million` FROM database" 
          f"WHERE Platform IN  ({','.join('?' for _ in list_table)}) ORDER BY Firm", (list_table))"

c.execute("SELECT Firm, Platform, `Sale in million` FROM database" 
          f"WHERE Platform IN  ({','.join('?' for _ in list_table)}) ORDER BY Firm", (list_table))"
```

How do you use f-string in multiple lines?

Comment: Never use f-string for building SQL queries. See for example this: https://github.com/arogozhnikov/python3_with_pleasure/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from essentially invalid multi lines and not really any fault of [f-string.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). Note that you only need to use your variables inside the `{}` parenthesis and not pass them separately with `f-string` syntax. Use triple quotes or backslashes at end of strings to use multi line strings. [Link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

```
test = "this is a 
       bad multiline " #Raises SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

test = ''' this is a 
         valid multiline'''

a = "answer"

print(f'''test
        is complete. check {a} ''')
```